# Power BI DAX - How to filter based on another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to achieve the following result:

Based on one table that gives the filter values (Table1), which has 4 entries, which are the slicer options:

"2019 vs 2022 YAG"
"2019 vs 2022 YTD"
"2021 vs 2022 YAG"
"2021 vs 2022 YTD"

I want that when one of these options is selected, this filters the year in another table (Table2).

I was able to write the following syntax but I am getting an error "the expression refers to multiple columns. multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value":

```
    Year Slicer = 
SWITCH (
    LASTNONBLANK( ( Table1[Choice]), 1 ),
    "2019 vs 2022 YAG", FILTER(Table2, Table2[YEAR] = OR(2022,2019)),   
    "2019 vs 2022 YTD", FILTER(Table2, Table2[YEAR] = OR(2022,2019)),    
    "2021 vs 2022 YAG", FILTER(Table2, Table2[YEAR] = OR(2022,2019)),    
    "2021 vs 2022 YTD", FILTER(Table2, Table2[YEAR] = OR(2022,2019))
)
```

I know that this error could be solved with a function like SUM, but the problem is I have several columns that I would need to sum. What I want is simply to filter by the years I have chosen (and after that apply the same formula to filter by month).

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/